# What is copy/move constructor choosing rule in C++? When does move-to-copy fallback happen?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-constructor

The first example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    unique_ptr<int> ref;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A(const int i) : ref(new int(i)) { }
    ~A() = default;
};

int main()
{
    A a[2] = { 0, 1 };
   return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly. So here the MOVE constructor is used.

Let's remove the move constructor and add a copy one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    unique_ptr<int> ref;
    A(const A&a) 
        : ref( a.ref.get() ? new int(*a.ref) : nullptr )
    {  }
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A(const int i) : ref(new int(i)) { }
    ~A() = default;
};

int main()
{
    A a[2] = { 0, 1 };
   return 0;
}
```

Now the compilation falls with the error "*use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’*"
So the MOVE constructor is REQUIRED and there is no fall back to a COPY constructor.

Now let's remove both copy- and move-constructors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    unique_ptr<int> ref;
    A(const int i) : ref(new int(i)) { }
    ~A() = default;
};

int main()
{
    A a[2] = { 0, 1 };
   return 0;
}
```

And it falls with "*use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’*" compilation error. Now it REQUIRES a COPY constructor!
So there was a fallback (?) from the move constructor to the copy constructor.

Why? Does anyone have any idea how does it conform to the C++ standard and what actually is the rule of choosing among copy/move constructors?

Comment: Didn't I already answer exactly this question half an hour ago >.>

Comment: This question is much more specific. It is not the same question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no "fallback". It is called *overload resolution*. If there are more than one possible candidate in overload resolution then the best match is chosen, according to a complicated set of rules which you can find by reading the C++ standard or a draft of it.

Here is an example without constructors.

```
class X { };

void func(X &&) { cout << "move\n"; }            // 1
void func(X const &)  { cout << "copy\n"; }      // 2

int main()
{
    func( X{} );
}
```

- As-is: prints "move"
- Comment out "1": prints "copy"
- Comment out "2": prints "move"
- Comment out "1" and "2": fails to compile

In overload resolution, binding rvalue to rvalue has higher preference than lvalue to rvalue.

---

Here is a very similar example:

```
void func(int) { cout << "int\n"; }      // 1
void func(long) { cout << "long\n"; }    // 2

int main()
{
     func(1);
}
```

- As-is: prints "int"
- Comment out "1": prints "long"
- Comment out "2": prints "int"
- Comment out "1" and "2": fails to compile

In overload resolution, an exact match is preferred to a conversion.

---

In your three examples on this thread we have:

1: Two candidate functions; rvalue prefers rvalue (as in my first example)

```
A(const A&);
A(A&&);           // chosen
```

2: Two candidate functions; rvalue prefers rvalue (as in my first example)

```
A(const A&); 
A(A&&);           // chosen
```

3: One candidate function; no contest

```
A(const A&);      // implicitly declared, chosen
```

As [explained earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691820/why-does-the-compiler-require-a-copying-constructor-need-and-have-moving-one-an/24691907#24691907), there is no implicit declaration of A(A&&) in case 3 because you have a destructor.

For overload resolution it does not matter whether the function body exists or not, it is whether the function is declared (either explicitly or implicitly).

Answer (score 11):

The function that it's going to use is chosen before it checks if it is `delete`d or not. In the case that the copy constructor was available and the move constructor was `delete`d, the move constructor was still the best choice out of the two. Then it sees that it's `delete`d and gives you an error.

If you had the same example but actually removed the move constructor, rather than making it `delete`d, you'll see that it compiles fine and does fall back to use the copy constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    unique_ptr<int> ref;
    A(const A&a) 
        : ref( a.ref.get() ? new int(*a.ref) : nullptr )
    {  }
    A(const int i) : ref(new int(i)) { }
    ~A() = default;
};

int main()
{
    A a[2] = { 0, 1 };
   return 0;
}
```

This class does not have a move constructor declared for it at all (not even implicitly), therefore it cannot be chosen.

Comment: So the choice (the choosing process) depends on has it one constructor or two? That seems wired. So a deleted constructor and an absent constructor are not the same?

Comment: @user3544995 There choosing process depends on which constructors are declared. It will choose the best-match constructor, as in all overloading situations. And yes, a `delete`d constructor and absent constructor are *not necessarily* the same. It is possible for an absent constructor to be implicitly declared as `delete`d though. In this case it is not - it is just not implicitly declared at all.